# how to set scroll position in infinite scroll

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-infinite-scroll-component for Infinite scroll inside Autocomplete of @mui/material
to get paginated data, but the issue is when I am getting new page data scroll moves to the top, how can I solve this issue, please help me with this.

This is the code and I also tried to resolve this issue using useRef but it didn’t work

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
    .
    .
    .
    {code...}

    const InfinteScroll: React.FC = (props) => {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {code..}

    const fetchData = {...code}

    return (
       <div>
         <Autocomplete
           value={value}
           {code..}
           PaperComponent={(params) => (
            <InfiniteScroll
               height={400}
               dataLength={dataLength}
               hasMore={hasMore}
               next={fetchData}
            >
          <div>
            {children}
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
    )}
  />
</div>
```

);
};